# Relative positioned HTML elements overlapping parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have some quite specific requirements for elements (at the moment these elements are spans, but this is not important for my question) that have to be displayed inside a web page.

*The basic problem is that elements which are positioned relatively inside a fixed height div can be expanded, i.e. can change their height, and they should overlap the containing div if they don't fit inside it after expanding.*

More specific, the major requirements are:

- The number of the elements is variable (they can be added and removed by the user).
- The elements should be arranged inside an area (a div at the moment) according to normal text flow, i.e. displayed from left to right inside one line, and from top to botton if there are several lines of elements. The width of the elements is not fixed, they usually have different widths.
- The containing div usually has to have a fixed height showing only one line of the elements, but can be expanded by the user to 'full size' to show all elements.
- The elements themself can have a changable height. Some of them can themself be expanded, for example they have dropdown menus. But, when the elements are expanded, the height of the containing div should not change. When such a dropdown menu is opened, this menu should overlap the div if needed. The elements can also represent tree structures, which can be expanded by the user, and which should overlap the div.
- Further requirements are that the elements should be rearrangable inside the div using drag&drop (I use JQuery Sortable for this purpose), and can also be moved (dragged) out of the div or moved (dropped) from somewhere else into the div (at the moment using also JQuery for that).

I am failing to realize the overlapping feature. The typical answer for this kind of problem seems to be, that absolute positioning should be used for the elements. But this does not seem to be feasible in my situation, because I need the usual text flow, and it would be too much effort to implement this flow using absolute positioning. Does somebody have an idea on how to realize these requirements?

I am sorry that I do not have specific code to show, but the complete code is already quite complex, and would be out of scope for presenting here. If needed, I can try to implement a simplified example, but I hope that someone can provide help with the general problem.

Comment: try posting the part the code... :)

Comment: @oliverm If you can post some code that shows your problem then maybe someone can help you fix it. Or, put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You might be interested in [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) since it has a flexible grid system. With a few tweaks (using jQuery) the overlapping stuff can be managed I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround on your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8dgr/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <span class="item">very long item</span>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    background-color:red;    /* to show the container's boundary */
    font-size:12px;
}

.container span{
    position:relative;    /* vital for setting the z-index item */
    float:left;
    display:block;        /* otherwise, margin will be ignored */
    padding:1em;          /* just for creating some space between items */
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    var expansion_amount = 100; //expansion amount in pixels

   $('.item').hover(
       function(){
           //mouse on
           $(this).css({
               'background-color':'green',
               'z-index':'100',
               'height':$(this).height() + expansion_amount + 'px',
               'margin-bottom': -expansion_amount + 'px'
           });
       },
       function(){
           //mouse off
           $(this).removeAttr('style');
       }
   );
});
```

the key feature here is to use of **negative margin** values. As much as the item will grow in height or width, it must get the same negative margin in that direction.

This code can also be written in pure css, but it requires knowledge of current item's height, or use of css3 calc.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpfull, I did not know about this feature of negative margins. I tried to make it work with my code. One problem that I have with it is that expanding the elements is not directly under my control. I use some ui control libraries for rendering dropdown menues and trees, and they have an internal handling of expand events, and it is not easy to intervene with them. Maybe I can get this to work, but a solution which does not require the calculation and setting of the margin at expand time would make it easier for me. Apart from that, your code reflects my problem very well

Comment: As I said if you don't want to use javascript at all, you can use some of the new CSS3 features like "calc", although it's not very well supported yet. check this out. http://caniuse.com/#search=calc, i'll edit the answer to cover the "calc" feature.

Comment: Maybe you can give me more details on how your script handles the expansion. I mean, does it change only the height property?

Comment: Thank you. In case of a dropdown menu, I am using AngularStrap for rendering this. If the user clicks on a button inside the span to open the menu, the AngularStrap ui control (i.e. Angular Directive) renders the menu, and thus implicitely changes the height. In case the element is a tree, I use JQuery DynaTree to realize the tree. When the root node inside the span is expanded, this ui control does everything needed to render the tree.

Comment: I also looked at calc(), but I could not figure out how to set the margin based on the height of the element

Comment: That's a bit of a problem. Maybe you can use spans to float easily across your container, and add an expanding absolute positioned menu to each. something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9KpTb/ . changing the menu's height won't affect the layout of the spans.

Comment: BTW it's not possible to use calc in your problem. margins calculate percent values based on the element's width, not it's height.